# cleaning up list of list of list in R

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have a problem with multiple level list in R. Here is small example of structure of my data.

```
library(purrr)

> example
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  id.value id.name    value
1        2     Tim -1.68956
2        4    Jack  1.23950
3        5    Mary -0.10897
4        3  Joseph -0.11724
5        1  Kermit  0.18308

[[1]][[2]]
  id.value id.name    value
1        6     Tim  0.50381
2        2    Jack  2.52834
3        1    Mary  0.54910
4        4  Joseph  0.23821
5        5  Kermit -1.04889
6        3     Red  1.29476

[[1]][[3]]
  id.value id.name    value
1        4     Tim -0.47279
2        1    Jack -1.06782
3        2    Mary -0.21797
4        3  Joseph -1.02600
5        5  Kermit -0.72889

[[1]]$main.id
[1] 123


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  id.value id.name    value
1        2     Tim -1.16554
2        4    Jack -0.81852
3        1    Mary  0.68494
4        3  Joseph -0.32006
5        5  Kermit -1.31152

[[2]][[2]]
  id.value id.name     value
1        2     Tim  0.821581
2        4    Jack  0.688640
3        5    Mary  0.553918
4        3  Joseph -0.061912
5        1  Kermit -0.305963

[[2]][[3]]
  id.value id.name    value
1        2     Tim  0.80018
2        1    Jack -0.16393
3        4    Mary  1.24292
4        5  Joseph -0.93439
5        3  Kermit  0.39371

[[2]]$main.id
[1] 234
```

So structure to my understanding is list of list of list, which includes data.frame and normal vector. Usually I get something out of these with `purrr map`, but now I can't get deep enough. End result should look like `result` (sorry if some values are out of place, but doing that by hand is error prone).

```
> head(result, 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  list.id sub.list.id id.value id.name  value
    <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1     123           1        2 Tim     -0.333
2     123           1        4 Jack    -1.02 

> tail(result, 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  list.id sub.list.id id.value id.name value
    <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     234           3        5 Joseph  0.548
2     234           3        3 Kermit  0.239
```

`list.id = main.id`, which I get hands on with `map_dbl(example, c("main.id"))`

`sub.list.id` = last list number in that list of list of list. In this example it runs from 1 -> 3 for each main list.

```
[[1]]
[[1]]**[[1]]**
  id.value id.name      value
1        2     Tim -1.6895557
2        4    Jack  1.2394959
3        5    Mary -0.1089660
4        3  Joseph -0.1172420
5        1  Kermit  0.1830826
```

Other variables should be self explanatory.

I'm usually working with `purrr map`, but if there are other good ways to solve these complicated lists I'm open. I have tried unlist, but it totally breaks the structure, which I don't think is needed. I'm currently trying to `bind_cols` (with data.frame and vector) -> and then try to `bind_rows` with `.id`, but haven't succeeded with anything meaningful yet.

Data:

```
example <- list(list(structure(list(id = structure(list(value = c(2L, 4L, 
                5L, 3L, 1L), name = c("Tim", "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit"
                )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 5L)), value = c(-1.6895556640288, 
                1.23949588599841, -0.108965972315484, -0.117241961787958, 0.183082613838439
                )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 5L)), structure(list(
                    id = structure(list(value = c(6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L), name = c("Tim", 
                    "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit", "Red")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                    6L)), value = c(0.503812447155119, 2.52833655070411, 0.549096735635542, 
                    0.238212920794043, -1.04889314358654, 1.29476325458416)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                6L)), structure(list(id = structure(list(value = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 
                3L, 5L), name = c("Tim", "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), value = c(-0.472791407727934, -1.06782370598685, -0.217974914658295, 
                -1.02600444830724, -0.72889122929114)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), main.id = 123), list(structure(list(id = structure(list(
                    value = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L), name = c("Tim", "Jack", "Mary", 
                    "Joseph", "Kermit")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), value = c(-1.16554484788995, -0.818515722513129, 0.684936077925063, 
                -0.320056419276819, -1.31152241139676)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), structure(list(id = structure(list(value = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 
                3L, 1L), name = c("Tim", "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), value = c(0.821581081637487, 0.688640254100091, 0.553917653537589, 
                -0.0619117105767217, -0.305962663739917)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), structure(list(id = structure(list(value = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 
                5L, 3L), name = c("Tim", "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), value = c(0.800176865835429, -0.163930968642975, 1.24291877493732, 
                -0.93438505805516, 0.393708652215792)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), main.id = 234))
```

Expected output:

```
result <- structure(list(list.id = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 
            123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 234, 234, 234, 234, 
            234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234), sub.list.id = c(1, 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
            2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), id.value = c(2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 6, 2, 
            1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 
            4, 5, 3), id.name = c("Tim", "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit", 
            "Tim", "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit", "Red", "Tim", "Jack", 
            "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit", "Tim", "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", 
            "Kermit", "Tim", "Jack", "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit", "Tim", "Jack", 
            "Mary", "Joseph", "Kermit"), value = c(-0.33320738366942, -1.01857538310709, 
            -1.07179122647558, 0.303528641404258, 0.448209778629426, 0.0530042267305041, 
            0.922267467879737, 2.05008468562714, -0.491031166056535, -2.30916887564081, 
            1.00573852446226, -0.709200762582393, -0.688008616467358, 1.0255713696967, 
            -0.284773007051009, -1.22071771225454, 0.18130347974915, -0.138891362439045, 
            0.00576418589988693, 0.38528040112633, -0.370660031792409, 0.644376548518833, 
            -0.220486561818751, 0.331781963915697, 1.09683901314935, 0.435181490833803, 
            -0.325931585531227, 1.14880761845109, 0.993503855962119, 0.54839695950807, 
            0.238731735111441)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
            31L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hairy, and `tidyr::unnest` doesn't seem to work properly for some reason. Nevertheless,

```r
library(purrr)

example %>% 
    set_names(map_chr(., 'main.id')) %>%    # store IDs as names for easy recovery
    map(keep, is.data.frame) %>%    # drop now superfluous `main.id` elements
    map_dfr(    # for each sublist
        function(sublist) { 
            map_dfr(    # for each element
                sublist, 
                ~dplyr::bind_cols(set_names(.x$id, ~paste0('id.', .x)), .x[2]),    # unnest
                .id = 'sublist.id'    # simplify sublist to data frame, adding element ID column
            )
        }, 
        .id = 'list.id') %>%    # simplify list to data frame, adding element ID column
    readr::type_convert()    # fix types of data stored as names
#>    list.id sublist.id id.value id.name       value
#> 1      123          1        2     Tim -1.68955566
#> 2      123          1        4    Jack  1.23949589
#> 3      123          1        5    Mary -0.10896597
#> 4      123          1        3  Joseph -0.11724196
#> 5      123          1        1  Kermit  0.18308261
#> 6      123          2        6     Tim  0.50381245
#> 7      123          2        2    Jack  2.52833655
#> 8      123          2        1    Mary  0.54909674
#> 9      123          2        4  Joseph  0.23821292
#> 10     123          2        5  Kermit -1.04889314
#> 11     123          2        3     Red  1.29476325
#> 12     123          3        4     Tim -0.47279141
#> 13     123          3        1    Jack -1.06782371
#> 14     123          3        2    Mary -0.21797491
#> 15     123          3        3  Joseph -1.02600445
#> 16     123          3        5  Kermit -0.72889123
#> 17     234          1        2     Tim -1.16554485
#> 18     234          1        4    Jack -0.81851572
#> 19     234          1        1    Mary  0.68493608
#> 20     234          1        3  Joseph -0.32005642
#> 21     234          1        5  Kermit -1.31152241
#> 22     234          2        2     Tim  0.82158108
#> 23     234          2        4    Jack  0.68864025
#> 24     234          2        5    Mary  0.55391765
#> 25     234          2        3  Joseph -0.06191171
#> 26     234          2        1  Kermit -0.30596266
#> 27     234          3        2     Tim  0.80017687
#> 28     234          3        1    Jack -0.16393097
#> 29     234          3        4    Mary  1.24291877
#> 30     234          3        5  Joseph -0.93438506
#> 31     234          3        3  Kermit  0.39370865
```

Comment: I will go with this, I was little bit too clever and some work is needed for me to use this with real data. Ingredients are here and will try to solve it on my own. Thanks.

Comment: If this list is originating from `jsonlite::fromJSON`, not telling it to simplify to data frames can make this sort of thing simpler. [roomba](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/roomba) is also useful, but in this case won't pull IDs for you.

Comment: yes, this is fromJSON, I was trying to cherry picking and thought I can get away with only this small example. That cursed data.frame in that last list is kicking my butt in all my attempts. Will be back in a week, if I don't get it. Thanks.

Comment: @alistaire `tidyverse` doesn't support data.frame columns as I understand it, but list columns containing data.frames are fine of course, this will work : `example[[1]][[1]] %>% transform(id=split(id,seq(nrow(id)))) %>% unnest`. notice I had to use `tranform` because `mutate` refused to go there . Note also that `as_tibble(example[[1]][[1]])` will fail with `Error: Column 'id' must be a 1d atomic vector or a list`.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper ah! Yep, that's it. I really wish `jsonlite::fromJSON` would only make tibble-legal/less-silly data frames.

Comment: Would this be easier if my list of list was list column in tibble? At least we wouldn't have to worry about main.id?

Comment: Yes, that would simplify things, as that way every sublist element will be in the same format.

Answer (score 1):

My take on a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse):

map_dfr(example, 
    ~ cbind(.['main.id'],            # put main_id as our first column
             map_dfr(.[-length(.)],  # build the rest of the table from previous elements
             ~bind_cols(             # for each of them takout manually .id col and rename
               rename_all(.$id,~paste0("id.",.)),
               .['value']),
             .id = "sub.list.id")))  # the .id parameter will do the required indexing
#    main.id sub.list.id id.value id.name       value
# 1      123           1        2     Tim -1.68955566
# 2      123           1        4    Jack  1.23949589
# 3      123           1        5    Mary -0.10896597
# 4      123           1        3  Joseph -0.11724196
# 5      123           1        1  Kermit  0.18308261
# 6      123           2        6     Tim  0.50381245
# 7      123           2        2    Jack  2.52833655
# 8      123           2        1    Mary  0.54909674
# 9      123           2        4  Joseph  0.23821292
# 10     123           2        5  Kermit -1.04889314
# 11     123           2        3     Red  1.29476325
# 12     123           3        4     Tim -0.47279141
# 13     123           3        1    Jack -1.06782371
# 14     123           3        2    Mary -0.21797491
# 15     123           3        3  Joseph -1.02600445
# 16     123           3        5  Kermit -0.72889123
# 17     234           1        2     Tim -1.16554485
# 18     234           1        4    Jack -0.81851572
# 19     234           1        1    Mary  0.68493608
# 20     234           1        3  Joseph -0.32005642
# 21     234           1        5  Kermit -1.31152241
# 22     234           2        2     Tim  0.82158108
# 23     234           2        4    Jack  0.68864025
# 24     234           2        5    Mary  0.55391765
# 25     234           2        3  Joseph -0.06191171
# 26     234           2        1  Kermit -0.30596266
# 27     234           3        2     Tim  0.80017687
# 28     234           3        1    Jack -0.16393097
# 29     234           3        4    Mary  1.24291877
# 30     234           3        5  Joseph -0.93438506
# 31     234           3        3  Kermit  0.39370865
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through nested items as follows

```
list.id <- c(); sub.list.id <- c(); id.value <- c(); id.name <- c(); value <- c(); r <- 0

for (i in 1:length(example)) {

  list.id.value <- example[[i]]$main.id

  for (j in 1:(length(example[[i]])-1)) {

    sub.list.id.value <- j

    for (k in 1:nrow(example[[i]][[j]][1])) {
      r <- r + 1

      list.id[r] <- list.id.value %>% as.numeric()
      sub.list.id[r] <- sub.list.id.value %>% as.numeric()
      id.value[r] <- example[[i]][[j]][[1]][k, "value"] %>% as.numeric()
      id.name[r] <- example[[i]][[j]][[1]][k, "name"]       
      value[r] <- example[[i]][[j]][[2]][k] %>% as.numeric()

    }

  }

}

result <- data.frame(list.id, sub.list.id, id.value, id.name, value) # %>% as.tibble()
result
```